# Could not initialize class com.kaltura.client.Client

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

I am using kaltura get media api inside servlet to get metadata information. below is the code present inside my doGet method of Sling-servlet. It is giving an error when i hit the servlet from AEM. I have deploy the bundle containing this servlet and also servlet is registered successfully.

---

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException, IOException {

        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            Client client = KalturaMetadataServlet.generateKalturaClient();
            String entryId = "*******";
            int version = -1;
            MediaService.GetMediaBuilder requestBuilder = MediaService.get(entryId, version)
                    .setCompletion(new OnCompletion<Response<MediaEntry>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Response<MediaEntry> result) {
                            System.out.println("This is final getMediaType:"+result.results.getMediaType());
                            System.out.println("This is final thumbnailUrl:"+result.results.getThumbnailUrl());
                            out.print(result);
                        }
                    });
            APIOkRequestsExecutor.getExecutor().queue(requestBuilder.build(client));

            // out.println(CodeExample.str);
            //out.println("<html><body>");
            // out.println("<h1>This value was returned by an AEM Sling Servlet bound by using a Sling ResourceTypes property</h1>");
            // out.println("</html></body>");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    public static Client generateKalturaClient() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setEndpoint("https://www.kaltura.com/");
        Client client = new Client(config);
        try {
            String session = client.generateSessionV2(
                    "**********************",
                    "*******@*****.com",
                    SessionType.ADMIN,
                    *******,
                    86400, "");
            client.setSessionId(session);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to start Kaltura session");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return client;
    }
```

---

Comment: Could you please be any more specific about the error?

Comment: Can you please provide the error or stacktrace for the error?

Comment: In the `catch` block of the `generateKalturaClient()` method you should log the exception, at least with `e.printStackTrace();`, because then you don't know the reason why it failed.

Comment: Please provide more information, since it is not clear what the issue could be.